# JavaScript: Using an object's property in another property?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

In my Grunt build script I have an object that holds most of my paths, like so:

```
var project_config = {
    project_paths: {
        build: 'assets/css',
        docs: 'docs',
        src_scss: 'src/scss/**/*.scss',
        yaml: grunt.file.readYAML('docs/config.yml')
    }
};
```

As you can see, `docs` can be found again in 'yaml', because it is just a path.

**How can I use `docs` in `yaml`?**

Doing it like so didn't work, probably because the object can't access itself:

```
var project_config = {
    project_paths: {
        build: 'assets/css',
        docs: 'docs',
        src_scss: 'src/scss/**/*.scss',
        yaml: grunt.file.readYAML(docs+'/config.yml')
    }
};
```

Using Grunt templating also didn't work: `yaml: grunt.file.readYAML('<%= project_paths.docs %>/config.yml')`

Comment: Did you try `'<%= project_paths.docs %>/config.yml'` ? Assuming `project_config` is the grunt configuration object.

Comment: @FelixKling Woops yes! Sorry, thats just a typo in my question. Will edit now.

Comment: A JavaScript property in a literal *cannot be directly used* from inside said literal. (Using forms of delayed evaluation does not count as 'direct'; there may something special with Grunt, otherwise that's the answer to the question..)

Comment: Oh well... I guess at the moment you are reading the YAML file, Grunt did not process your config object yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you want to access the path, Grunt did not process the configuration object yet. You can process the template string "manually" with [`grunt.template.process`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template#grunt.template.process):

```
var project_config = {
    project_paths: {
        build: 'assets/css',
        docs: 'docs',
        src_scss: 'src/scss/**/*.scss'
    }
};
project_config.project_paths.yaml = grunt.file.readYAML(
    grunt.template.process(
        '<%= project_paths.docs %>/config.yml',
        {data: project_config}
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't find this function!